# Running nested batches inside a batched chain of jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-queue

I have a batched series of chained jobs, and inside those chains I need to be able to batch other jobs.

Say I have 3 Clients

For Each Client I need to

1. Sync their details with an external API
2. Create 0 or more new cases and sync them individually
3. Update 0 or more existing cases and sync them individually

And I need the wrapping batch to keep track of when this is all finished.

I currently have the following structure:

```
$jobs = $clients->map(fn(Client $client) => [
   new SyncClientJob(...),
   new CreateMultipleCasesJob(...),
   new UpdateMultipleCasesJob(...)
]);

Bus::batch($jobs)->name('BatchA')->etc()
```

In CreateCasesJob, something along the lines of

```
public function handle()
{
   $jobs = $collection_of_new_cases->map(fn(Case $case) => new CreateSingleCaseJob($case));
   Bus::batch($jobs)->dispatch();
}
```

CreateCasesJob and UpdateCasesJob should both dispatch their own batch of jobs, since each case needs to be synced individually

The problem is of course that the Create/Update jobs are "complete" in the chain when they're dispatched, not when all their internal jobs are completed. So the `BatchA` job will be marked as completed when it hasn't yet synced any cases.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having each batch of jobs dispatch an event in the ->finally() callback. The listener for that event would then build and start the next batch.